# VueJs - Add class on window resize

Tags: javascript, vue.js, responsive

Using Vuejs, what is the correct way to add and remove a class depending on what size the browser window is?

I've been looking at 'v-transitions', however, all the examples I have come across are using an on click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the best option is to add a native window event listener on component mounted and manage classes depending on dimensions.
Then you might use `:class="..."` binding (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) in your template and pass an array of classes there.
Look at this fiddle for a very close example https://jsfiddle.net/hr77p7qb/3/

Comment: Why do you want to react on window resize? Are you doing responsive app?

Comment: Yes I am. I want to add a class to my left hand menu for animation purposes